# Simplify $\frac {3^{(-3+x)}6^{(3-x)}}{3\cdot4^x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

$$\frac {3^{(-3+x)}6^{(3-x)}}{3\cdot4^x}$$

What is the simplest form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \frac{3^{x-3}\cdot 2^{3-x} \cdot 3^{3-x} }{3\cdot 2^{2x}} =2^{3-x-2x}\cdot3^{x-3+3-x-1}=\frac{2^{3-3x}}{3}.$$

Comment: @mohmmed What do you mean by "simplest form"? Note that Tacet most likely gave you those hints to get at this answer, which is a fraction in lowest ("simplest") terms, since the numerator is a power of $2$ and the denominator is $3$.

Comment: your answer right i just kidding with you my friend :))

Comment: @mohmmed Now I see :D

Answer (score 2):

You should know two facts.

$$\begin{split}
a^x \cdot a^y &= a^{x+y}\\
(a\cdot b)^x &= a^x \cdot b^x
\end{split}$$

---

Then you can easily obtain next two facts
$$\begin{split}
\left(a^b\right)^c &= \underbrace{a^b \cdot a^b \cdot ~\dots~ \cdot a^b}_{\text{c  times}} = a^{b+b+\dots+b} &= a^{b\cdot c}\\
\frac{a^x}{a^y} &= a^x \cdot \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{y} = a^x \cdot a^{-y} &= a^{x-y}
\end{split}$$

---

**Hint**:
$$4^{x} = \left(2^2\right)^{x} = 2^{2x}$$

**Hint2**:

$$ 6^{3-x} = (3\cdot2)^{3-x} = 3^{3-x} \cdot 2^{3-x}$$

---

**Solution**:

$$\begin{split}
\frac{3^{(-3)+x}\cdot 6^{3-x}}{3 \cdot 4^{x}} &=
\frac{\left(3^{3-x}\right)^{-1}\cdot 3^{3-x}\cdot 2^{3-x}}{3 \cdot 2^{2x}}\\
&=\frac{\left(3^{-1}\right)^{3-x}\cdot 3^{3-x}}{3}
\cdot \frac{2^{3-x}}{\cdot 2^{2x}}\\
&=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3} \cdot 3\right)^{3-x}}{3}
\cdot 2^{(3-x)-(2x)}\\
&= \frac{1}{3} \cdot 2 ^{3\cdot (1-x)} = \frac{1}{3 \cdot8^{x-1}}
\end{split}$$

Comment: i will try to solve it, wait, can you Correct the expressing in the Question above

Comment: Why not $\dfrac {8}{3\cdot 8^x} = \dfrac 1{3\cdot 8^{x-1}}$

Comment: @amWhy Just subjective preferences. Without any wise explanation. But you have right. It will be more simplified in your form.

Comment: To be honest, "simplest" in cases like this is a subjective call (not "well-defined) ;-)

Comment: sir, how you convert the Symbols and characters to math formula?? like the formula you solve it by

Comment: @mohmmed: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).
You can also take a look at source of my answer. And you should consider acceptance the answer, if it was helpful. 

----

amWhy: I know, but... you know too. ;-) Something can be more standardized.

Comment: there is no converter website, when i can write my equations and convert it to a math formula and copy and paste it easily??

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{3^{-3+x}\cdot2^{3-x}\cdot 3^{3-x}}{3\cdot2^{2x}}=\frac{2^{3-3x}}{3}=\frac{8^{1-x}}{3}$$

Comment: @mohmmed, what do you mean by wrong? Not the same as in your answer sheet?

Comment: your answer it's very correct .. thenk you :)